geometry nodes hair refusing to render / set hair curve profile doesn't work
Trying to make grass that looks like carpet. I can't figure out how to add bulk to the geometry nodes hair curves so that it will render. The set hair curve radius modifier just wont show up at any size.




To make Geonodes Hair render, it needs to be applied to a Curves object. Check it out, in outliner it looks like this:

If it doesn't, you can add it with  Shift+A ⇾ Curve ⇾ Empty Hair (or Fur)

that's what i did. it wont let me add an empty hair curve if its not linked to a mesh and i can't use fur because it's smallest size is way too big
